# library for mesh manipulation/deformation

Tags: c++, 3d

Does anyone know of nice C++ library to get the Union, difference and intersection of 3d meshes?

Comment: have you used CGAL? Can you say a few words about your progress on union and difference of 3d meshes, please?

Comment: I haven't got round to using CGAL yet but the API looks like exactly what I was looking for: http://doc.cgal.org/4.2/CGAL.CGAL.3D-Boolean-Operations-on-Nef-Polyhedra/html/classCGAL_1_1Nef__polyhedron__3.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/). It supports various boolean operations.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the options available are:

- [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/)
- [VCGlib](http://vcg.sourceforge.net/index.php/Main_Page)
- [TriMesh](http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/proj/trimesh2/)

Comment: Do the last two also support boolean operations?

Comment: @Bart: Not sure of the last two, but CGAL does support boolean operations for sure.

Comment: CGAL looks good but the only guide to building on windows includes downloading visual C++!

Comment: @tm1rbrt: And you're using...?

Answer (score 1):

Try Geometros sgCore - http://www.geometros.com/sgcore/review.htm - very robust and powerfull library for C++/ C#/ Obj-C